# twig render controller() passes an array instead of an object

Tags: symfony

I'm trying to render a controller amd send the `$from->createView()` object. Now, this works in <=2.1, but I can't seem to get it to work in 2.2.

Here is the code:

EventsContoller::newAction

```
return $this->render('SplurginEventsBundle:SplurginEventEvents:new.html.twig', array(
    'entity' => $entity,
    'form'   => $form->createView(),
    'existingFiles'=>$existingFiles,
    'editId'=>$editId,
    'isNew'=>true,
));
```

Right now the `form` variable is holding an object of the form view, I verified with `var_dump`.

In twig:

```
{% render controller('JulLocationBundle:Googlemaps:placesAutocomplete' , {locationForm: form}) %}
```

When I go to the controller `placesAutocomplete` and again use `var_dump`, I can see that it is an array and not an object.

How can I send an object and not an array to the controller being rendered?

## EDIT :

this issue was resolved , with lot's of edits .. if any one is interested in the JulLocationBundle i will provide a pull request in a few days .

Comment: what is locationForm , a url parameter ? doesnt the render tag takes a url or a path ?

Comment: @mpm `locationForm` is a parameter in the method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
{{ render(controller('JulLocationBundle:Googlemaps:placesAutocomplete' , {locationForm: form})) }}
```

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#embedding-controllers

Comment: it is that same as im using .. i have tried it before , didnt work . thats though :)

Comment: you are using {% render %} tag and not the function in your exemple.Anyway let me check , i'll come back to you ASAP.

Comment: thanks for your concern , i really need to get this fixed , i have tried your solution again .. and still that same problem

Comment: this seams to be an issue (or more of the way that symfony operates now ) , i will accept the answer .. thanks for the help